# MySQL error code 1005 / errno: 150

Tags: mysql, xampp, mysql-workbench

I'm using a XAMPP 5.6.19-0 as a MySQL Database server and managing via MySQL Workbench (Mac OS 10.11.3). I'm trying to create some tables, with foreign keys, and im getting this error:

> Error Code: 1005. Can't create table `imobiliaria24h`.`proprietario` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

This is the code I'm trying to use:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PROPRIETARIO (
NOME VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
CPF INT NOT NULL,
TELEFONE INT NOT NULL,
CORRETOR_CPF INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (CPF),
FOREIGN KEY (CORRETOR_CPF) REFERENCES CORRETOR(CPF)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS IMOVEL(
ENDERECO VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
TIPO ENUM('ALUGUEL', 'VENDA'),
INQUILINO_CPF INT,
PROPRIETARIO_CPF INT,
VALOR_ALUGUEL_PRECOVENDA INT NOT NULL,
NUM_QUARTOS INT NOT NULL,
METRAGEM INT NOT NULL,
NUM_BANHEIROS INT NOT NULL,
VALOR_CONDOMINIO INT NOT NULL,
IDADE INT NOT NULL,
HORA_REGISTRO TIME NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(ENDERECO),
FOREIGN KEY (INQUILINO_CPF) REFERENCES INQUILINO(CPF),
FOREIGN KEY (PROPRIETARIO_CPF) REFERENCES PROPRIETARIO(CPF) 
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS INQUILINO(
NOME VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
CPF INT NOT NULL,
TELEFONE INT NOT NULL,
FIADOR BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
INADIMPLENCIA INT NOT NULL,
CORRETOR_CPF INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (CPF),
FOREIGN KEY (CORRETOR_CPF) REFERENCES CORRETOR(CPF)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CORRETOR(
NOME VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
CPF INT NOT NULL,
TELEFONE INT NOT NULL,
ANOS_CASA SMALLINT NOT NULL,
TRABALHA_FDS BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
TRABALHA_NOITE BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (CPF)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

The interesting thing is that, if I create the table separately, only the ones that references each other, for example, I created first PROPRIETARIO and CORRETOR, second INQUILINO, and at last IMOVEL, and this way everything worked. I'm not understanding why I'm getting the error creating them all together in a "single command".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you running that exact script? If so, it looks like you're trying to create the foreign keys before you've actually crated the tables they're referencing.

Try changing the order in which you build them.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS CORRETOR(
NOME VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
CPF INT NOT NULL,
TELEFONE INT NOT NULL,
ANOS_CASA SMALLINT NOT NULL,
TRABALHA_FDS BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
TRABALHA_NOITE BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (CPF)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PROPRIETARIO (
NOME VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
CPF INT NOT NULL,
TELEFONE INT NOT NULL,
CORRETOR_CPF INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (CPF),
FOREIGN KEY (CORRETOR_CPF) REFERENCES CORRETOR(CPF)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS INQUILINO(
NOME VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
CPF INT NOT NULL,
TELEFONE INT NOT NULL,
FIADOR BOOLEAN NOT NULL,
INADIMPLENCIA INT NOT NULL,
CORRETOR_CPF INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (CPF),
FOREIGN KEY (CORRETOR_CPF) REFERENCES CORRETOR(CPF)
)ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS IMOVEL(
ENDERECO VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
TIPO ENUM('ALUGUEL', 'VENDA'),
INQUILINO_CPF INT,
PROPRIETARIO_CPF INT,
VALOR_ALUGUEL_PRECOVENDA INT NOT NULL,
NUM_QUARTOS INT NOT NULL,
METRAGEM INT NOT NULL,
NUM_BANHEIROS INT NOT NULL,
VALOR_CONDOMINIO INT NOT NULL,
IDADE INT NOT NULL,
HORA_REGISTRO TIME NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(ENDERECO),
FOREIGN KEY (INQUILINO_CPF) REFERENCES INQUILINO(CPF),
FOREIGN KEY (PROPRIETARIO_CPF) REFERENCES PROPRIETARIO(CPF) 
)ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: Bingo! It worked. How dumb I feel right now! Just beggining with MySQL. Thanks for the help, though!

Comment: Not a problem. Even people who have been doing this stuff for years make mistakes which seem obvious in hindsight. Don't feel bad about it, it's all part of the learning process. Good luck!